# Which religions is this song inspired by and what do the metaphors/symbols mean?

Tags: meaning, metaphor

I was going to ask this in music.stackexchange, but decided to ask here, as I think the subject is inspired Judaism and Christianity. If there's a more appropriate site, please let me know and I can ask there.

The question is related to this one - https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/12481/what-is-the-word-used-in-this-line-of-this-song-for-which-ive-typed-up-these-ly.

Would the lyrics in the linked song above be inspired by any particular religion and what do the metaphors mean? I think it is either or both of Judaism and Christianity, and maybe Islam, but I am not sure.

The author is Mary S. Applegate, whom I assume to be the same Applegate as the [author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Susan_Applegate) of "[The Power of Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Love_(Celine_Dion_single))". On Applegate's Wikipedia page's Associated acts section, I don't find any religion-based artists, if it is the same writer.

In particular, what could the name of the artist mean? Who or what is Gabriel? What is the perfect circle of infinity that Gabriel shows? What is the sacred kingdom? What are the forbidden skies?

I showed this to a Jewish friend, who mentioned that sin is disturbance of harmony. I'm curious to know more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is NOT a Christian song ("Saint of Sin" is blatant blasphemy), but more like new age borrowing some religious elements of spiritual journey into union with God.  Therefore, this question is not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lyrics of this song suggest ideas of rebirth and reincarnation, which is neither Christian, Jewish nor Islamic but can be found within Buddhism, Hinduism and new age spirituality.

Rebirth in Buddhism refers to the teaching that the actions of a person lead to a new existence after death, in an endless cycle called saṃsāra. Rebirth is one of the foundational doctrines of Buddhism.

Reincarnation is a key belief within Hinduism. In Hinduism, all life goes through birth, life, death, and rebirth and this is known as the cycle of saṃsāra.

“New Age” beliefs include belief in reincarnation, astrology, psychics and the presence of spiritual energy in physical objects like mountains or trees.  New Agers believe that consciousness pervades the universe and that personal consciousness does not end with the death of the physical body.

Although Christianity, Judaism and Islam believe in the archangel Gabriel, the Gabriel of the Bible is one of God’s good and holy angels. He has a favored position as an angel who “stands in the presence of God” (Luke 1:19), and he was selected to deliver important messages of God’s particular love and favour to individuals chosen to be part of God’s plan.  As a messenger from God, the idea that he “shows us a passageway that seems to have no beginning and no end” is unbiblical.

More information about Gabriel here: https://www.gotquestions.org/angel-Gabriel.html

Comment: While reincarnation is not taught by the major Christian denominations, it should be noted that 30% of American Christians believe in reincarnation. https://www.pewforum.org/2021/11/23/views-on-the-afterlife/